# google news search php - Why wont this sample code run?

Tags: php, curl

Can't get my head around why this sample code from Google is producing an error on line 12, unexpected $?

I've been using PHP on and off for a few years now, but this has really got me stuck, Any help appreciated.

Apologies if the question is too dumb, I'm just lost here - thanks.

```
<?php 

$url = "https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/newsv=1.0&q=legit%20news&userip=5.148.12.26";

// sendRequest
// note how referer is set manually
$homeUrl = "http://smbh.co.uk";
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, $homeUrl);
$res = curl_exec$(ch);
curl_close($ch);

// now, process the JSON string
$json = json_decode($res);
// now have some fun with the results...

echo $json;

?>
```

Comment: `$res = curl_exec$(ch);`................. should be `$res = curl_exec($ch);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Line 12 is this:

`$res = curl_exec$(ch);`

It should be

`$res = curl_exec($ch);`

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the issue already noted where you've misplaced a dollar sign, there's also a typo in the URL for the Google News Search API. The correct URL has a question mark between `news` and `v`, e.g.

```
https://https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/search/news?v=1.0&q=example
                                                            ^^^
```

However, note that the Google News Search API has been deprecated **since May 2011**, and is currently subject to strict rate limits. I would recommend that you avoid using it in new applications, as it may stop working at any time!